# UINavigationController showing wrong navigationItem after calling pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table view that displays a new view when one of its items is pressed. The problem is the new view's `navigationItem` property isn't being displayed. Instead, the previous view's (the table view) navigation item appears to be displayed (the table view's navigation bar animates in unchanged).

Here is the press handler that pushes the new view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSLog(@"--- showing asset picker");
  ELCAssetTablePicker *picker = [[ELCAssetTablePicker alloc] initWithNibName:@"ELCAssetTablePicker" bundle: nil];
    picker.parent = self;

  picker.assetGroup = [self.assetGroups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  //[picker.assetGroup setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];

  [picker release];
}
```

And here is the `viewDidLoad` method of the view being pushed (`ELCAssetTablePicker`) where the title and buttons of `self.navigationItem` are updated:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
  [self.tableView setAllowsSelection:NO];

  NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  self.elcAssets = tempArray;
  [tempArray release];
  UINavigationItem* navigationItem = self.navigationItem;

  UIBarButtonItem *doneButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneAction:)] autorelease];

  [navigationItem addBackBarButtonItemWithTitle:@"Back" forController:self];
  [navigationItem addRightBarButtonItem:doneButtonItem];
  [navigationItem setTitle:@"Loading..."];

  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(preparePhotos) withObject:nil];
}
```

Why isn't the navigation bar being updated when a new view is pushed to the `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Wow. I didn't know anyone used MRC any more. Brave.

Comment: @rmaddy It's an old project that I've been tasked with doing a little upkeep on. If it were up to me, I wouldn't be using Objective-C at all.

Comment: Did you find any solution. I'm facing this exact weird bug for one of my VC in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Make `navigationItem` global. Its reference is getting killed I guess. Why don't use simple `self.navigationItem`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
  [self.tableView setAllowsSelection:NO];

  NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  self.elcAssets = tempArray;
  [tempArray release];

  UIBarButtonItem *doneButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneAction:)] autorelease];

  [self.navigationItem addBackBarButtonItemWithTitle:@"Back" forController:self];
  [self.navigationItem addRightBarButtonItem:doneButtonItem];
  [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Loading..."];

  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(preparePhotos) withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: I am using `self.navigationItem`: `UINavigationItem* navigationItem = self.navigationItem;` The only reason I created a local variable is to make it easier to access in the debugger.